# Error using LaTeX for plot rendering in MacOS 10.11

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, osx-elcapitan

I recently made a clean install of OSX 10.11, installed Anaconda with python 3.5, Xcode, MacTex 2015 and updated all of these.

I have a problem when I want to use LaTeX in matplotlib.

Here is a short example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import rc

rc('font', **{'family': 'serif', 'serif': ['Computer Modern']})
rc('text', usetex=True)

b = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13],dtype=np.float)
bStd = np.array([1.4, 0.6, 0.3, 1.1],dtype=np.float)

N = len(b) 
ind = np.arange(N,dtype=np.float) 
width = 0.8   

FS=11 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5.9055, 3.937))

Test = ax.plot(ind,b)      
yerr = plt.errorbar(ind,b,bStd)

ax.set_title('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...', fontsize = FS, family = ['serif'])            
ax.set_xticks(ind)         
ax.set_xlim([-width, N-1+width])
ax.set_xticklabels( ('A','B','C','D'), fontsize = FS, family = ['serif'])
ax.set_ylabel('Value / $X/yy^2$',multialignment="center",fontsize = FS, family = ['serif'])
ax.set_ylim(0,20)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('Test.pdf', format='pdf',bbox_inches='tight')
```

When I try to use TeX in matplotlib, I receive the following:

```
RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
b'lp'
Here is the full report generated by LaTeX:
```

I think that Spyder does not know how to access LaTeX. May this be a problem of the new rootless feature in El Capitan?

I already searched the web and of course Stackoverflow, but none of the suggestions, I found there, helped me.

Do you have any idea?

I just started to learn how to work with python, therefore I am really inexperienced, which might be visible in my example.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Using Spyder as installed with MacPorts, I have the very same problems, but using Python3 as installed by MacPorts on a Mac OS Terminal, everything compiles fine (which seems strange since Spyder relies on this version of Python...).

As a workaround, if using the Terminal is fine for you, you may run directly your script from the Terminal (however, make sure that you use python as installed by anaconda by giving the explicit path to the executable), but this defeats the purpose of installing a nice GUI such as Spyder.